# I want to run code at a certain video timestamp in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, video

I want to do a cool CSS background change to match with the video.

I use this code:

```
    document.getElementById("video").addEventListener("playing",video,false);

function video(){
    if(document.getElementById('video').currentTime >= 3.466) {
    document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = "black";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('video').addEventListener("timeupdate", video());
    }
}
```

I was hoping that when the video reaches 3.466 seconds it would change the color of the background but, it doesn't and Firefox says that there is too much recursion.

Comment: Compare the difference between the first use of `addEventListener` and the second. See any possibly important differences? Also, you don’t want to be attaching event listeners over and over every time the function gets called!

Answer (score 2):

so `timeupdate` is the event you're looking for. You can listen to it once and check to see if the `currentTime` is past your 3.466 seconds. I put a CodePen together - https://codepen.io/motionharvest/pen/yLGqwqZ?editors=1111

```
//I'm gonna use these later, so I'll define them here
let video = document.getElementById("video");
let body = document.body;

//listen to the video element for `timeupdate`
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", onPlaying, false);

//this fires every `timeupdate`
function onPlaying(){
    if(video.currentTime >= 3.466) {
        body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    }
}
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Event listener checks the current time of the video and changes the background

```js
function changeBackgrounds() {
    const video = document.querySelector('#video');
    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
        if (video.currentTime >= 2 && video.currentTime < 3) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        } else if (video.currentTime >= 3 && video.currentTime < 4) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        } else if (video.currentTime >= 4) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        }
    });
}

changeBackgrounds();
```

```css
body { width: 100%; height: 100svmax; background-color: pink; } .wrapper { width: 500px; } video { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <video id="video" autoplay controls>
        <source src="https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```